# Python can Union recursively contain itself?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Is it possible to create a type that is a union of which one item references the type?

See the following example use case. This fails because `Serialized` has not yet been declared.

```py
from typing import List, Dict, Union 

class MyClass:
    # (...)

    Serialized = Union[Dict[str, Serialized], List[Serialized], str, int, float, bool]

    def serialize(self) -> Serialized:
        ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484) which defines the type hints, you can use what they call [forward references](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) to reference types that have not yet been defined.

So you could do:

```py
from typing import Union, Dict, List

class MyClass:
    # (...)

    Serialized = Union[Dict[str, 'Serialized'], List['Serialized'], str, int, float, bool]

    def serialize(self) -> Serialized:
        ...
```

Comment: Forward references exist, but I don't think `mypy` can make use of the resulting recursively defined type.

Comment: Looks like the latests version of `mypy` can handle the basic forward references ([source](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/731)), and [PEP 563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) introduced the ability to postpone the evaluation of annotations, including type hints, so I understand well this would enable it.

Comment: The ability to *define* recursive types is distinct from the ability to use them for type checking. See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/731 (which indicates there is some support now, but I haven't test it yet to see if the support works here).